# Given the definition of Kuratowski pairs, Pairs have right identity conditions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm supposed to prove that $\{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\} = \{\{c\}, \{c,d\}\}$ iff $a = c \wedge  b = d.$

I'm trying to show that if {{a}, {a,b}} = {{c}, {c,d}} then ((a = c) & (b = d)) on the assumption that a = b.

However, I'm only ever able to show that (a = c) follows and not that (b = d). 
Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: You have to split the cases: *(i)* $\{ a \} = \{ c \}$ and *(ii)* $\{ a \} = \{ c,d \}$ and derive in both cases the result: $a=c$ and $b=d$.

Comment: You need also some "trivial" results: 1) $x \in \{ x \}$, 2) $x \in \{ u,v \} \text { iff } x=u \lor x=v$, 3) $\{ x \} = \{ x,x \}$.

Comment: See also the post [defining-sets-using-pairs-check-if-definition-satisfies-the-pair-correctness-property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565068/defining-sets-using-pairs-check-if-definition-satisfies-the-pair-correctness-pr)

Comment: To @MauroALLEGRANZA Why is it the case that I have
(i) {a} = {c}; AND (ii) {a} = {c, d}?

Isn't it the case that if {a} = {{c}, {c,d}} then I know that EITHER {a} = {c} OR {a} = {{c, d}}? And from this given a disjunction elimination I cannot derive the conjunction of (a=c) & (b = d)?

Comment: Yes; when I say two cases, I mean the two possible cases: EITHER $\{ a \} = \{ c \}$ OR $\{ a \} = \{ c, d \}$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA but then how would I derive b = d from {a} = {c}?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the Axiom of Extensionality, that $x=y \iff \forall z\;(z\in x\iff z\in y)$: Let $S=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}=\{\{c\},\{c,d\}\}.$

Suppose $a\ne c.$ Then $\{a\}\ne \{c\}$ but $\{a\}\in S$ so $\{a\}=\{c,d\}$ so $c=d=a.$

Therefore $a\ne c\implies a=c,$ so we must have $a=c.$

Now if  $b=a=c$ then $S=\{\{a\}\}=\{\{a\},\{a,d\}\}$ so $d=a,$ so $d=a=c=b.$

Or if $b\ne a=c$ then $\{c\}=\{a\}\ne\{a,b\}\in S$ so $\{a,b\}=\{c,d\}=\{a,d\}.$ And $(b\ne a\land \{a,b\}=\{a,d\})\implies b=d.$

The reverse implication $(a=c\land b=d)\implies \{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}=\{\{c\},\{c,d\}\}$ is obvious.

Comment: If that is how your Axiom of Extensionality looks, then $=$ must be built into your underlying logic, and then you don't actually need to appeal to the axiom for the $\Rightarrow$ direction -- that is a primitive fact of equality.

Answer (score 0):

First suppose that $a \neq b$ and $c \neq d$. Given that you already know that $a = c$, look at
$$
\begin{align*}
\{ b \} &= \{a,b \} \setminus \{a \} \\
&= ( \bigcup \{ \{a \}, \{a,b\} \} ) \setminus \{ a \} \\
&= ( \bigcup \{ \{c \}, \{c,d \} \} ) \setminus \{ a \} \\
&= ( \bigcup \{ \{c \}, \{c,d \} \} ) \setminus \{ c \} \\
&= \{ c, d \} \setminus \{ c \} \\
&= \{ d \}
\end{align*}
$$
and now observe that
$$
b = \bigcup \{b \} = \bigcup \{d \} = d.
$$

If $a = b$. Then 
$$
\begin{align*}
\{ \{a \}, \{a,b \} \} &= \{ \{a \} \} \\
&= \{ \{c\}, \{c,d \} \}
\end{align*}
$$

and hence $\{a\} = \{c\} = \{c,d \}$, the only element of the above set. But this yields $a = c = d$ and thus $a = b = c =d $, as desired.

The remaining case $c = d$ follows by symmetry.

Comment: The first equality here only holds under the assumption that $a\ne b$. Otherwise $\{a,b\}\setminus\{a\}=\varnothing$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm That's right. I implicitly assumed $a \neq b$ and $c \neq d$. I'll edit that.

Comment: Where does $\{a,\{a,b\}\}$ come from in your second part? That is not a Kuratowski pair. (And the first equality you write in that case is not true unless $a=\varnothing$ or $a=\{b\}$).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Sorry, I'm just terrible at writing LaTeX outside of my Emacs environment... Should be fixed now.